# Creating a shell script which can spawn multiple concurrent processes which call a specified web service

Tags: bash, shell, sh

I am trying to create a load testing shell script essentially what I am looking to do is have the script spawn some N number of concurrent processes and have each of those processes call a specified URL and perform a few basic actions. I am having a hard time figuring this out - any help would be awesome!!

Comment: What do you mean "perform a few basic actions"? Could you provide more details? Because as it is this seems like a job for apache benchmark

Comment: Performing curl, wget then an upload

Answer (score 2):

If you really need to use shell, take a look at [Bash: parallel processes](http://www.nrtm.org/index.php/2011/05/09/bash-parallel-processes/). But there are load testing tools like [ab (Apache HTTP server benchmarking)](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/programs/ab.html) that can do the job for you.

You can use *ab* as simple as:

```
ab -n 10 -c 2 -A myuser:mypassword http://localhost:8080/
```

For more examples, look at [Howto: Performance Benchmarks a Webserver](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/howto-performance-benchmarks-a-web-server.html).

Comment: Thanks - I am trying to replicate a individual user for N number of users concurrently using a .sh script.

Comment: I am working on using apache benchmarking tool - and am wondering how to pass login credentials to the site I am calling using the -A flag?

Comment: You can use the -A flag for BASIC Authentication credentials.

Answer (score 2):

have a look at this article:

http://prll.sourceforge.net/shell_parallel.html

as described:
"Parallel batch processing in the shell

How to process a large batch job using several concurrent processes in bash or zsh

This article describes three methods of parallel execution: the first is not very performant and the other two are not safe to use. A more complete solution is called prll and can be found here. This article is not meant to be good advice, but instead laments the state of scriptable job control in shells."